# Background color in email signature on mac mail

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm trying to code an email signature
An clients like thunderbird, outlook, gmail it works as intended but on mac mail there is a problem with color codes.

Any `background-color` or `background` or even `bgcolor=""` (6 hex, 3hex, rgb, doesn't matter) that i set is changed to some different color
for example:
#121d52 is changed to #c2cbf7
#b8e9fd is changed to #396070

How to force it to not changing this color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in dark-mode when I have switched to light-mode everything was perfect again.

to enable dark/light mode detection in email client I had to add those meta tags

```html
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
```

and then in css I had to force those color in dark-mode

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    /* ... */
}
```